how to get bundles in the directory defined by output.path when using webpack-dev-server
I'm reading the webpack5 doc. In the document's Guides -> Development -> Choosing a Development Tool -> Using webpack-dev-server,there is a tip as follows

webpack-dev-server serves bundled files from the directory defined in output.path, i.e., files will be available under http://[devServer.host]:[devServer.port]/[output.publicPath]/[output.filename]

but i can't get bundles in the directory defined by output.path
firstly, I used the npx webpack to generate files in the dist directory
then I modified dist/index.bundle.js to distinguish between index.bundle.js in memory
finally I start a server by npx webpack serve and accessed localhost:8080/dev/index.bundle.js
I found it's not the index.bundle.js in dist directory
├── assets
├── dist
│   ├── index.bundle.js
│   ├── index.html
│   └── runtime.bundle.js
├──src
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js")
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
        publicPath: "/dev",
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        clean: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpaclPlugin({
            title: "webpack-dev-server"
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        static: path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets")
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: "single"
    }
}

I don't think there is any relationship between output.path and webpack dev server

Why did you use static: path.resolve(__dirname, "./assets") instead of static: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist")?

@LinDu Because I know that files in the directory specified by static can be accessed, and the tip says "webpack-dev-server server bundle files from the directory defined in output. path", after reading this tip, my guess is that I can access both the content in the directory specified by static and the content in the directory specified by output.path, so I write static and output.path as different values

This is also what confuses me. I think output.path should be the output directory of the file after executing npx webpack. Why does this tip describe it this way
